# How to pick up neighboring rows of certain rows in dataframe, spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

There is a dataframe containing 2 columns: [**time**: Timestamp, **value**: Double].

Here we define a rule to find outliers of **value**. Except that, we want to pick up neighboring rows of the rows containing outliers.
For example, the dataframe is:

[image: dataframe]

Row 7 in red contains the outlier value we defined, and we want to get Row 4~10 (3 rows next to Line 7).

How to implement that? I guess `rowsBetween` might be an alternative but I do not know how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Window-functions with `rowsBetween` like this:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1,220),
  (2,220),
  (3,220),
  (4,220),
  (5,220),
  (6,230),
  (7,220),
  (8,220),
  (9,220),
  (10,220)
).toDF("time","value")

df
  .withColumn("is_outlier",$"value">220)
  .withColumn("outlier_region",max($"is_outlier").over(Window.orderBy($"time").rowsBetween(-3L,3L)))
  .show()
```

gives:

```
+----+-----+----------+--------------+
|time|value|is_outlier|outlier_region|
+----+-----+----------+--------------+
|   1|  220|     false|         false|
|   2|  220|     false|         false|
|   3|  220|     false|          true|
|   4|  220|     false|          true|
|   5|  220|     false|          true|
|   6|  230|      true|          true|
|   7|  220|     false|          true|
|   8|  220|     false|          true|
|   9|  220|     false|          true|
|  10|  220|     false|         false|
+----+-----+----------+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! Besides, what if there is overlap? For example time 6 and 7 are outliers, and in such case, their common neighbors would be considered as close to one of them. Take time 8 for example, how can we show that time 8 is the neighbor of both time 6 and 7, rather than one of them?

Comment: @Susu in such a case work with numbers instead of booleans and use `sum` instead of `max`, a value of 2 would then mean that two outliers are nearby